# I am unable to understand what is the statement struct node *a [26] used for.. after we make the structure of a node for linked list

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, declaration

```
struct node{
     int data;
     struct node*next;
};
struct node * a[26];
```

Are we making an array of node pointers or assigning size to the node pointer?
Please help me out I am stuck with this problem.

Comment: Your question is unclear.... The text in the question indicates that you want to know what `struct node * a[26];`. However, the title indicates that you want to know what the array `a` is used for. Two different things.

Comment: Without more context (i.e. code) we can't tell what the array is used for... It's likely to be head-pointers for 26 different linked lists. The number 26 makes me think about the latin alphabet with 26 different letters (a, b, c, ... , x, y, z). Maybe elements/nodes are added to 1 of the 26 linked list based on a letter... On the other hand, that would make more sense if data was a char pointer... But again, more code is needed to figure that out

Comment: @SupportUkraine: “However, the title indicates that you want to know what the array a is used for” The title asks what the statement (properly declaration) “struct node *a [26]” is used for, not what `a` is used for.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If the wording is clear to you, fine... To me it isn't. Have a nice day.

Comment: You will have an array of linked lists; perhaps one for each letter of the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

`struct node * a[26];` declares `a` to be an array of 26 pointers to `struct node`.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration

```
struct node * a[26];
```

declares an array with name `a` with `26` elements of the pointer type `struct node *`.

These two declarations

```
struct node{
     int data;
     struct node*next;
};
struct node * a[26];
```

also may be rewritten as one declaration the following way

```
struct node{
     int data;
     struct node*next;
} * a[26];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node * a[26];
```

Let's examine it step by step:

A realistic way of reading declarations in `C` is boustrophedonically, i.e. alternating right to left and left to right, starting from the first identifier when reading from the left until we a see a semi-colon, a bracket or reach the end of the left side.

```
a[26];
```

declares an array of 26 elements. We see a semi-colon so we go back to the left:

```
* a[26];
```

This becomes an array of 26 pointers. We continue to the left because we haven't reached the end yet.

```
struct node * a[26];
```

This becomes an array of 26 pointers to an object of type `struct node`.

In a nutshell, `a` is an array of `26` pointers to an object of type `struct node.`

NB that the actual rules are determined by the formal grammar and mirror operator precedence, as stated in the comment below.

Comment: “Boustrophedonically” means lines of text are written alternately from left to right; it has nothing to do with single-line declarations in C. The declarations of C are sometimes described as alternating or spiraling, but this is an inaccurate description. The actual rules are determined by the formal grammar and mirror operator precedence.

Comment: *The actual rules are determined by the formal grammar and mirror operator precedence.* ---> You're right, but I believe that'd be a realistic description of how to read them. That's how I learned at least.